# Run two service node and python inside docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.5 AS python-build
ADD . /test
WORKDIR /test
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt  &&\
    pip install oauth2client

FROM node:10-alpine AS node-build
WORKDIR /test
COPY --from=python-build ./test ./
WORKDIR /test/app/static
RUN npm cache verify && npm install && npm install sass -g &&\
    sass --no-source-map scss/layout/_header.scss:css/layout/_header.css &&\
    sass --no-source-map scss/layout/_footer.scss:css/layout/_footer.css &&\
    sass --no-source-map scss/layout/_side_menu.scss:css/layout/_side_menu.css &&\ 
    sass --no-source-map scss/layout/_error_component.scss:css/layout/_error_component.css &&\ 
    sass --no-source-map scss/components/_input_box.scss:css/components/_input_box.css &&\
    sass --no-source-map scss/components/_button.scss:css/components/_button.css &&\
    sass --no-source-map scss/components/_loading_mask.scss:css/components/_loading_mask.css &&\ 
    sass  --no-source-map scss/components/_template_card.scss:css/components/_template_card.css &&\
    sass --no-source-map scss/pages/_onboarding_app.scss:css/pages/_onboarding_app.css &&\
    sass  --no-source-map scss/pages/_choose.scss:css/pages/_choose.css &&\
    sass --no-source-map scss/pages/_adapt.scss:css/pages/_adapt.css &&\
    sass --no-source-map scss/pages/_express.scss:css/pages/_express.css &&\
    sass --no-source-map scss/pages/_experience.scss:css/pages/_experience.css &&\ 
    sass --no-source-map scss/pages/_features.scss:css/pages/_features.css &&\
    sass --no-source-map scss/pages/_request_demo.scss:css/pages/_request_demo.css &&\ 
    npm run build
WORKDIR /test/node-src
RUN npm install express


FROM python:3.5-slim
COPY --from=python-build /root/.cache /root/.cache
WORKDIR /test
COPY --from=node-build ./test ./
RUN apt-get update -yq \
    && apt-get install curl -yq \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR /test/node-src
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "server.js"] #RUN NODE SERVICE INSIDE NODE/SRC
WORKDIR /test
EXPOSE 9595
CMD [ "python3", "./run.py" ] #RUN PYTHON SERVICE INSIDE /TEST
```

i am trying to run two service inside one container node and python but only  one is running i want to run both service in one container on kubernetes.

EDIT : 1

```
FROM python:3.5 AS python-build
ADD . /test
WORKDIR /test
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt  &&\
    pip install oauth2client

FROM node:10-alpine AS node-build
WORKDIR /test
COPY --from=python-build ./test ./
WORKDIR /test/app/static
RUN npm cache verify && npm install && npm install sass -g &&\
    sass --no-source-map scss/layout/_header.scss:css/layout/_header.css &&\
    sass --no-source-map scss/layout/_footer.scss:css/layout/_footer.css &&\
    sass --no-source-map scss/layout/_side_menu.scss:css/layout/_side_menu.css &&\ 
    sass --no-source-map scss/layout/_error_component.scss:css/layout/_error_component.css &&\ 
    sass --no-source-map scss/components/_input_box.scss:css/components/_input_box.css &&\
    sass --no-source-map scss/components/_button.scss:css/components/_button.css &&\
    sass --no-source-map scss/components/_loading_mask.scss:css/components/_loading_mask.css &&\ 
    sass  --no-source-map scss/components/_template_card.scss:css/components/_template_card.css &&\
    sass --no-source-map scss/pages/_onboarding_app.scss:css/pages/_onboarding_app.css &&\
    sass  --no-source-map scss/pages/_choose.scss:css/pages/_choose.css &&\
    sass --no-source-map scss/pages/_adapt.scss:css/pages/_adapt.css &&\
    sass --no-source-map scss/pages/_express.scss:css/pages/_express.css &&\
    sass --no-source-map scss/pages/_experience.scss:css/pages/_experience.css &&\ 
    sass --no-source-map scss/pages/_features.scss:css/pages/_features.css &&\
    sass --no-source-map scss/pages/_request_demo.scss:css/pages/_request_demo.css &&\ 
    npm run build
WORKDIR /test/node-src
RUN npm install express


FROM python:3.5-slim
COPY --from=python-build /root/.cache /root/.cache
WORKDIR /test
COPY --from=node-build ./test ./
RUN apt-get update -yq \
    && apt-get install curl -yq \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR /test/node-src
RUN npm install pm2 -g
EXPOSE 3000
CMD pm2 start server.js #RUN NODE SERVICE INSIDE NODE/SRC
WORKDIR /test
EXPOSE 9595
CMD [ "python3", "./run.py" ] #RUN PYTHON SERVICE INSIDE /TEST
```

i also tried pm2 service for node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are trying to achieve it is not a recommended design. typically a docker container should run a single service. as a result, there is no built-in way in docker to get this to work, although it is still possible, using a wrapper script or tools like [supervisord](https://supervisord.org), you can manage multiple services inside the container-

or as for the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/): (i went for the supervisord option since to me it looks more clean and manageable than the wrapper script way)

> Use a process manager like supervisord. This is a moderately
>   heavy-weight approach that requires you to package supervisord and its
>   configuration in your image (or base your image on one that includes
>   supervisord), along with the different applications it manages. Then
>   you start supervisord, which manages your processes for you. Here is
>   an example Dockerfile using this approach, that assumes the
>   pre-written supervisord.conf, my_first_process, and my_second_process
>   files all exist in the same directory as your Dockerfile.
>
> ```
> FROM ubuntu:latest
> RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y supervisor
> RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor
> COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
> COPY my_first_process my_first_process
> COPY my_second_process my_second_process
> CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
> ```

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

what you are currently using in your Dockerfile is called [multisage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) which is by far **not** what you really want.

Comment: Hi thanks for writing answer, from your answer it look like it is not possible to run two service but can't i run supervisor my multi-stage built ?

Comment: @HarshManvar i said "its **not impossible**". sorry if that wasnt clear enough. edited my answer now. sure you can do it with supervisor. good luck!

Comment: hi thankyou for wrting answer and i also got solution. 'supervisord' is good way but i simply added the command in CMD pm2 node node-src/server.js && python run.py

Comment: At the end i am simply running one CMD command in docker file. CMD pm2 start path of node-service && python path to python file.

Comment: this should work for small environments (thats kinda like whats supervisord is actually doing).  just keep in mind thats sometimes you would like a tool to let you manage the processes (e.g when the container goes down from any reason, you want to know more about whats going on, etc). good luck anyway